# HTTP Requests in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there a good tutorial or something similar for making HTTP requests and JSON in cocoa? As I'm playing around with the Simplenote API.

Answer (score 2):

For JSON parsing have a look at [BSJSONAdditions](http://blakeseely.com/blog/archives/2006/03/29/bsjsonadditions-12/)